# AppleScript to Make New Calendar in Specific Account

Tags: macos, applescript, calendar

The AppleScript Dictionary for macOS Calendar 10.0 (High Sierra) appears to have no API for addressing specific accounts.

For example…

```
set myCalendar to make new calendar with properties {name:"New Girl"}
```

…creates a calendar "On My Mac."  There seems to be no way to create a calendar in an iCloud or other calDAV account.

Have I had insufficient caffeine, or is the answer just plain "No"?

Answer (score 1):

You could use GUI scripting like this...

```
tell application "System Events"
    click menu item "iCloud" of menu 1 of menu item ¬
        "New Calendar " of menu 1 of menu bar item ¬
        "File" of menu bar 1 of application process "Calendar"
end tell
```

But one of the problems with this solution is you cannot set the properties of the calendar.  The new calendar will be named "Untitled"

Comment: Thanks, but for various reasons, GUI scripting is not an option.

Comment: @wch1zpink, you would `get the last calendar whose name is "Untitled"` then `set the properties of the result to {name:"New Name", description:"Some text"}`. The changes do take effect but, weirdly, aren't seen until you view the calendar's info.  A quick *Cmd-I* and *Return* via *System Events* is enough to get the updates reflected.