# Using AppleScript to delete an event still existing in Calendar?

Tags: applescript, calendar

I'm trying to write an AppleScript that clears a calendar (an iCloud one) of all of its events. I have the following:

```
tell application "Calendar"
    tell calendar "Test calendar"
        set the_events to every event
        repeat with current_event in the_events
            delete current_event
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

In the Script Debugger, I can see that the number of events in the list `the_events` is going down as it deletes each one. If I run the script again, Script Debugger tells me that there are now no events in the calendar. However I can still access and change the events in the Calendar app, be that on the same computer or on another device or the iCloud website.

What's going on here?

Comment: I tried using a where clause to select for all but one event in the calendar so that not every event was deleted but the result is the same.

Comment: Not sure what the proper protocol is for this reply.
It turns out that the calendar needs a refresh to update. 

Following a comment in [a separate post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314328/applescript-to-make-new-calendar-in-specific-account) by @CJK, you can ask to "Get info" on any calendar and the deleted events will disappear. 

I'm still getting use to how programming keystrokes works so what I did was close and open the application using:

`tell application "Calendar"
quit
delay 5
activate
end tell`